# Simple live jQuery form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I've always used the 'jQuery Engine Validation' plugin but this no longer works with version 2 of jQuery - can anyone recommend a simple live validation plugin that works with the latest version of jQuery. I just require it to validate against 'empty' fields and email addresses.

Comment: You could do that manually..?? If u insist on having a plugin to do that try jQuery Validate Plugin

Comment: ? someone actually downvoted this after being answered almost 3 weeks ago.. jeez :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [idealForms](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms)

it's a good alternative